# Joomla: alternative content for an article

Tags: internationalization, joomla, joomla1.5

I've just started work on an existing Joomla! site, and have a requirement to add an alternative language version of an article. Note that this isn't a full-internationalization effort - we don't need every part of the interface translated - just the need to have another 'version' of an article. Ideally, though, this would include more than just the core content - for example, title. I don't really want to create a second article because, in essence, this really is just a single article, and I don't want things like comments to be split between two separate articles.

Does anyone know if this can be done using joomla core?

If not, can anyone recommend an existing component that will do this?

Answer (score 0):

A good component for manage translations in Joomla 1.5 is [Joom!fish](http://www.joomfish.net/). It allows you to do a whole internationalization that, as you said, isn't exactly what you want to do. However I like to think in the long run so, if there's more change, I have not to restructure again and again just because of I haven't thought it before. Hence, if I were you, I would like to use Joom!fish anyway.

Comment: I'll look into Joom!fish although, as you suggest, it does sound like overkill for what we're trying to achieve in a short space of time. Maybe the time has come just to write a custom module/component.

Comment: I've taken a look at Joom!Fish and it does seem a bit like overkill. One 'issue' is that it appears to revolve around setting a language against the session'; this is not our requirement. We just need something that will allow 'temporary' viewing of an article's translation. I'm starting to look into using Joom!Fish and building a module which detects if a translation is available and presents a link to it if it is (this functionality doesn't seem to be present in Joom!Fish) but I'm still going to need to do something to supress the session stuff. Seems like there should be a nicer alternative

Comment: @BobbyJack I know that it already do what you're talking about and that is present the translation if it's present in the DB.

Comment: Do you know HOW it presents the translation? There's no "View this article in French" link on an article that I've added a French translation to. And, to reiterate, I don't want the reader to have to click a global "view site in French" link first - this has to be on an article-level rather than sitewide.

Comment: @BobbyJack Look at this site: http://www.parlaritaliano.it Here you can see the "View this article in LANGUAGE". (high-right corner)

Comment: That's not quite what I'm after because a) it switches the language attached to the session, rather than just as a on-eoff view b) it appears on every page, not just those pages which actually have a translation

Answer (score 0):

Well, as a short fix - Google Translator works and can be installed into your template you're using. 
Then you can set it to be hidden unless the users browser is set to use a different language as default - then a small pop-up box drops down and it asks to translate it using google translate.

If that's not the option you're looking for - joom!fish is a good component others rave about but I don't have much experience with personally.  Outside of that I'm not really sure.

Comment: We already have the translation, produced by a native speaker which, I believe, should provide a superior result than any automated translation. The tricky bit is just integrating the translation with the 'default language' article.

Comment: Well, you could always create a new article (the French version), then use put one of those 'in French' type links inside the English version - you could probably do something nifty with AJAX that would pull up just the main body of the French article in a lightbox or something.  Unless you're trying to steer clear of having the user click a link to get it translated?

Comment: that looks like exactly what we're going to do, in the short-term, at least. The disadvantage with this approach is that it creates a separation between the two articles so that labels will need to be duplicated, comments will be split between the two, etc. I think we're just going to have to put up with that for the meantime, though. The advantage with this approach is that it's very quick and simple to implement. Thanks.

Comment: No problem.  Not sure the commenting system that you're utilizing - perhaps there might be some that you could configure to use same commenting over multiple articles?  I'm not sure on that front - it doesn't seem like something people would want by default so it may be tough.  The benefit of using Ajax and a lightbox to pull up just the 'content' of that french article is that when they close it - they can leave comments on the original one - which is not perfect, but close... if you find a good answer let me know because you've got me curious.

Comment: Good point about the lightbox - I hadn't really thought of that. If going down that route, I'd probably use some kind of tabbing interface (e.g. jQuery tabs) to just switch between the two translations on the one page; as you point out, that has the effect of displaying a second article in a way that 'integrates' it with the original.

Comment: Yea, cool idea with the tabs - careful using JQuery - make sure to use it in noconflict mode if you do.  Mootools is the preferred JS Library for Joomla - although many people do use JQuery with success - just have to be careful how and when.

Comment: Yup - thanks for the heads-up. We're already using a module that includes jquery itself, but it calls jQuery.noConflict(); So, hopefully, any use of jQuery I add will be just as safe :)

Answer (score 0):

Hanny had a good idea that would be really easy to implement in an article with the right extension. You can use this extension -

http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/tabber

This would allow you to easily create tabs with the translations available anywhere you have them. The page above uses the extension to display the tabs, it would be trivial to implement.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like the route I'm going to follow, and I'm waiting for Hanny to edit his/her original answer to include the comments so I can up-vote! ;-) Thanks for ALL your answers to my joomla questions - all great responses! Are you a member of the joomla forums? Have you checked out the proposal for a joomla-specific SE site on area51?

Comment: I am on the Joomla forums but I have not seen that proposal. Sounds like a good idea to me, but I am probably a little biased.